# How can I determine why my PC wont shutdown fully

Tags: boot, bios, multi-boot, shutdown, desktop-computer

I have a custom built PC that started NOT fully shutting down ~month or so ago. OS shuts down, monitors turn off, LEDs around the power button shut off, but the fans keep whirring and internal case lights stay on. I don't know the exact when. Since then I have tried a bunch of things to address this to no avail:

- Disabling windows fastboot (dual boot)
- Checking Ubuntu system logs (dual boot)
- Unplugging all USB devices and drives
- Disabling anything related to what can wake/startup in BIOS
- Other random BIOS things
- Anything else google seems to indicate I do

But at this point it feels mostly like guess/test rather than any sort of logical process based on information. My question mostly lies around what can I do to make progress? Are there logs I can look at to see what's going on? In the BIOS or something? Are there ways to see if a device is sending a keep alive signal or a SSD is keeping it awake? Can DP monitors keep it alive through the graphics card? No idea where to go next.

EDIIT: This went away randomly after weeks....:shrug: ty

Comment: Update BIOS and any power drivers the system may have. Restart and test.

Comment: Depends on BIOS , OS and MOBO which are TBD

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this seems to have been replacing a dying fan on the GPU.  Some time after posting this question I noticed the fan making alot of noise.  After pulling the graphics card and installing a new fan, the system has shut down completely fine ever since.